# How large of a String does Sha256 produce?

Tags: java, hash, sha256

How large of a String does Sha256 produce?

Does the answer depend on how large of a String I am using to get a hash using Sha256?

I plan to store the Sha256-produced hash String in a mySQL table, in a column defined as a varchar(500).

Comment: 64 hexadecimal characters. `char(64)` would be sufficient.

Comment: hmm a quick google search shows this; "SHA256 hashes have 256 bits of output, which translates to 64 characters in hex. That's double the length of the 32-character MD5 hash in hex. Base64 encoded SHA256 characters are only 44 bytes in length (and the last = for padding is omitted anyway)."

Comment: yes and so what's the problem ?

Comment: @supercommando440: If a quick google search showed you that info then what is your question?

Comment: obviously the question has been answered.. after I posted it. So there' no problem.

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 generates a 256-**bit** hash.

But its **hexadecimal** representation will be 64 characters (2^256 = 16^64)

Ex **Text**: stackoverflow
**Hash**: 126cfbe1fd5413ba4d604c50a74bfc80471cec367b1604ade4d081f31c3f4f34

Hence **char(64)** would be a sufficient datatype for your column.

Comment: In other words: 256-bit integer represented as hexadecimal string where each hexadecimal character specifies 4 bit (16 values: 0,1,...,9,A,...,F) of the integer requires 256/4 = 64 characters.